How to Enable Claim Validation in Auth0 with Flutter?
I'm working on a Flutter application that uses Auth0 for authentication. I have implemented an AuthenticationService using the auth0_flutter package. The implementation works for the most part, but I'm encountering an issue when trying to log in.
Here is my AuthenticationServiceImpl class:
class AuthenticationServiceImpl extends AuthenticationService {
  @override
  Future<void> loginWithEmail({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    final auth0 = getIt<Auth0>();

    final audience = dotenv.env['AUTH0_AUDIENCE'];

    if (audience == null) {
      throw Exception('The AUTH0_AUDIENCE environment variable is not set');
    }

    final credentials = await auth0.api.login(
      usernameOrEmail: email,
      password: password,
      audience: audience,
      connectionOrRealm: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
    );

    await auth0.credentialsManager.storeCredentials(credentials);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> logout() async {
    final auth0 = getIt<Auth0>();

    await auth0.credentialsManager.clearCredentials();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> register({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    final auth0 = getIt<Auth0>();

    await auth0.api.signup(
      email: email,
      password: password,
      connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> isUserLoggedIn() async {
    final auth0 = getIt<Auth0>();

    final isLoggedIn = await auth0.credentialsManager.hasValidCredentials();

    return isLoggedIn;
  }

  @override
  Future<String> fetchUserEmail() async {
    final auth0 = getIt<Auth0>();

    final credentials = await auth0.credentialsManager.credentials();

    return credentials.user.email ?? '';
  }

  @override
  Future<void> resetPassword({required String userEmail}) async {
    final auth0 = getIt<Auth0>();

    await auth0.api.resetPassword(
      email: userEmail,
      connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
    );
  }
}

When attempting to log in, I encounter the following error:
E/a ( 4611): The request is made without validating claims. Enable claim validation by calling AuthenticationRequest#validateClaims()
D/j ( 4611): Trying to encrypt the given data using the private key.

Interestingly, the login process works correctly on the emulator, but I cannot log in on a real device.
I understand that I need to enable claim validation, but I'm not sure how to do this with the auth0_flutter package. Could someone guide me on how to modify my login request to include claim validation?
